# Nestjs validator constructor argument error

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, nestjs, joi

I'm trying to get the nest validator working as in the example in the 'pipes' document (https://docs.nestjs.com/pipes) section "Object schema validation" .  I'm trying the example using Joi which works except the passing of the schema from the controller to the validate service.

```
import * as Joi from 'joi';
import { PipeTransform, Injectable, ArgumentMetadata, BadRequestException 
} from '@nestjs/common';

@Injectable()
export class JoiValidationPipe implements PipeTransform {
  constructor(private readonly schema) {}

  transform(value: any, metadata: ArgumentMetadata) {
   const { error } = Joi.validate(value, this.schema);
     if (error) {
       throw new BadRequestException('Validation failed');
   }
   return value;
  }
}
```

The compiler complains:

> Nest can't resolve dependencies of the JoiValidationPipe (?). Please
>   make sure that the argument at index [0] is available in the current
>   context.

In the controller

```
@Post()
@UsePipes(new JoiValidationPipe(createCatSchema))
async create(@Body() createCatDto: CreateCatDto) {
  this.catsService.create(createCatDto);
}
```

there the compiler complains one argument given zero expected.

It looks like a declaration issue but I don't really know.  Why doesn't this work and how should I pass the schema to the service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you stated yourself `JoiValidationPipe` must *not* be declared as a provider in any module.

---

I can only reproduce the error with this code (not passing a schema):

```
@UsePipes(JoiValidationPipe)
async create(@Body() createCatDto: CreateCatDto) {
  this.catsService.create(createCatDto);
}
```

Make sure you do not have this anywhere in your code.

This works for me:

```
@UsePipes(new JoiValidationPipe(Joi.object().keys({ username: Joi.string().min(3) })))
async create(@Body() createCatDto: CreateCatDto) {
  this.catsService.create(createCatDto);
}
```

Comment: No, that doesn't make any difference.  It's the constructor of the JoiValidationPipe that's provoking the error.  Does 'schema' need a type?

Comment: Actually, both `@UsePipes` and `@Body` work for me. I can only reproduce your issue, if I write `@UsePipes(JoiValidationPipe)` without `new` and passing the schema. Are you sure you do not have another controller like this? What schema are you passing to the pipe? You can also try removing the `@Injectable()` from the pipe definition. It should also work without DI.

Comment: Interesting, I'm glad you rewrote the Joi.object as you did; I was not passing the schema correctly but even so it still failed to compile until I removed @Injectable from the pipe.  Now it works!  Should it work with @Injectable?

Comment: It should work with `@Injectable()` and it does for me. Have you made sure that this is the only place in your code where you're using  the `JoiValidationPipe`? If this does not work maybe try the usual stuff like `npm update` and throwing away `node_modules` and reinstalling. Or you can try reproducing the error in an empty project like I did and try to identify the difference that causes the error.

Comment: Removing JoiValidationPipe as a provider from app.module resolves the problem.  I thought all injectables had to be declared at module level.  It seems not!

Comment: I'm glad you could solve it. I've updated my answer, might help others with the same problem.